# As a Canadian, what are the legal requirements for working in the US?

Tags: usa, working-visas, canada, legal, canadian-citizens

I am considering a semi-permanent job in NYC (1-2 years), which would require moving from Toronto, Canada.

I am a Canadian citizen, have no criminal record, and as far as I know am eligible to work for any employer.

What legal requirements are there for me to work like this in the US?

Comment: Welcome to expats.SE.  What do you mean semi-permanent?

Comment: Just that I won't be there forever. It's a full time job but I'm not planning on spending the rest of my life in the US. I would hope 1-2 years but it may turn into 3+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to obtain a temporary worker visa in order to legally work in the US.

As a Canadian citizen you may be eligible for [TN Visa](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/tn-nafta-professionals) which has an initial period of stay of 3 years.  The requirements for application you can take look at the [CBP's site](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/citizens/tn-status).  Good news is that there doesn't seem to be a quota on the TN visa applicants.

You can also apply for an [H-1B visa](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/h-1b-specialty-occupations-and-fashion-models/h-1b-specialty-occupations-dod-cooperative-research-and-development-project-workers-and-fashion-models) if you qualify but you can only do this in 2015 as H1 status is subject to quota and for 2014 it has been filled.

In general you will need to have your perspective employer submit a [Petition for Nonimmigrant Worker](http://www.uscis.gov/i-129) and so on but you can review the respective sites for details and usually for employers lawyers do this kind of work.

There are other possible visas that may be available but these may be the more likely candidates.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Looks like I have some paperwork to fill out. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.